# Подскажите как зафиксировать шапку таблицы, чтобы при прокрутке зафиксировано было только тело. как это реализовать на CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Подскажите в чем ошибка, буду благодарен.

Цель чтобы в начале шла шапка, а только после нее вся остальная информация. 
Как это реализовать на CSS HTML?

```js
<script>
 /* System.out.println(ar.differentTime); */

 var windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight
   : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
 var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
 var docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
 var windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

 window.onload = function down() {
  var idInt = setInterval(function() {
   window.scrollBy({
    top : document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    left : 0,
    behavior : 'smooth'
   });

   if (pageYOffset >= docHeight - window.innerHeight - 1) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    clearInterval(idInt);
   }

  }, 20000)
 };
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
div.container {
 width: 100%;
 /* margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;  */
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

html {
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

/* header {
 font-size: 34pt;
 color: white;
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
 clear: left;
 text-align: center;
 height: 5vh;
} */
footer {
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 color: white;
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
 clear: left;
 text-align: center;
 height: 5vh;
}

article {
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #7F7F7F;
 /* height: 1500vh; */
 margin: 0 0 0;
 -webkit-column-span: all;
 column-span: all;
}

.lux {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 95%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
}

/* .lux tr:nth-child(2n) {
 background-color: #595959;
}

.lux tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
 background-color: #595959;
} */
.lux td {
 background-color: #595959;
 border: 3px solid white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.lux th {
 
}

.headTime {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 border: 0px;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 font-weight: normal;
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#headLable {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 border: 0px;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#head {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

.lable {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 border: 3px solid white;
 font-size: 2.5vw;
 background-color: #F79646;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.body {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 border-top: 2px solid grey;
 color: white;
}

.bodyleft {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 color: white;
}

.bodyTime {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 color: #F79646;
}

#header {
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.column {
 /* columns: 200px 1;
 column-gap: 30px;
 column-rule: 3px solid white;
 height: 100%; */
 margin-top: 0.5%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">    
<meta name="viewport" content="height=1440">
<title>ВЫЛЕТ</title>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container">
  <article>
 <table class="lux">
   <div id="headerMain"> 
  <div id="header">
  <table class="lux">
  
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th id="head" colspan="5"> ООО <th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th class="headTime" colspan="1">12:55</th>
      <th class="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
      <th id="headLable" colspan="1">ВЫЛЕТ</th>
      <th class="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
      <th class="headTime" colspan="1">21.02.2018</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th class="lable">РЕЙС</th>
      <th class="lable">ПУНКТ НАЗНАЧЕНИЯ</th>
      <th class="lable">КОД</th>
      <th class="lable">РАСПИСАНИЕ</th>
      <th class="lable">ВРЕМЯ ДО ВЫЛЕТА</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
 <table class="lux">  
<tbody>

   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">KK 1501</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Стамбул</td>
     <td class="body">IST</td>
     <td class="body">17:00</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:04</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1730</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Петропавловск-Камчат</td>
     <td class="body">PKC</td>
     <td class="body">17:00</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:04</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1302</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
     <td class="body">MRV</td>
     <td class="body">17:10</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:14</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">RU 449</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Сингапур</td>
     <td class="body">SIN</td>
     <td class="body">17:15</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:19</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1160</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Ростов -на-Дону</td>
     <td class="body">ROV</td>
     <td class="body">17:20</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:24</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1426</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Челябинск</td>
     <td class="body">CEK</td>
     <td class="body">17:25</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:29</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1362</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Саратов</td>
     <td class="body">RTW</td>
     <td class="body">17:25</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:29</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1364</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Ставрополь</td>
     <td class="body">STW</td>
     <td class="body">17:30</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:34</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 2036</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Бухарест</td>
     <td class="body">BUH</td>
     <td class="body">17:30</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:34</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1106</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Краснодар</td>
     <td class="body">KRR</td>
     <td class="body">17:35</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:39</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1140</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
     <td class="body">AER</td>
     <td class="body">17:35</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:39</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1214</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Самара</td>
     <td class="body">KUF</td>
     <td class="body">17:40</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:44</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1440</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Иркутск</td>
     <td class="body">IKT</td>
     <td class="body">17:40</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:44</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1414</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Екатеринбург</td>
     <td class="body">SVX</td>
     <td class="body">17:45</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:49</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 024</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
     <td class="body">LED</td>
     <td class="body">17:50</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:54</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1316</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
     <td class="body">MRV</td>
     <td class="body">17:55</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">4:59</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1260</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Уфа</td>
     <td class="body">UFA</td>
     <td class="body">18:00</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">5:04</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">RU 444</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Пекин</td>
     <td class="body">BJS</td>
     <td class="body">18:00</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">5:04</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1204</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Пермь</td>
     <td class="body">PEE</td>
     <td class="body">18:00</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">5:04</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
     <td class="bodyleft">SU 1006</td>
     <td class="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
     <td class="body">KGD</td>
     <td class="body">18:05</td>
     
      <td class="bodyTime">5:09</td>
     
     
    </tr>
   
   
   
  </tbody>
  
 </table>
 </div>
 </table>
</div>
 </article>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать для `body` `padding-top` равный высоте фиксированной части. Моё решение на JQuery. Может быть ещё нужно объединить в одну таблицу, а потом фиксировать шапку.

```js
var windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight :
  document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var body = document.body,
  html = document.documentElement;
var docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
var windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

window.onload = function down() {
  var idInt = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy({
      top: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    if (pageYOffset >= docHeight - window.innerHeight - 1) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      clearInterval(idInt);
    }

  }, 20000)
};
//Моё решение
function bodyPadding(){
  $('body').css('padding-top', $('#fix').outerHeight());
}
bodyPadding();
$(window).resize(bodyPadding)
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
div.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

html {
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

header {
  font-size: 34pt;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vh;
}

footer {
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vh;
}

.column {
  /* columns: 200px 1;
     column-gap: 30px;
     column-rule: 3px solid white;
     height: 100%; */
}

article {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #7F7F7F;
  color: white;
  /* height: 1500vh; */
  margin: 0 0 0;
  font-size: 38pt;
  -webkit-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
}

.lux {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.lux tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #595959;
}

.lux tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #595959;
}

.lux td {
  background-color: #595959;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.lux th {}

.headTime {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#headLable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

.lable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 30pt;
  background-color: #F79646;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30pt;
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
}

.bodyleft {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30pt;
}

.bodyTime {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: #F79646;
}

#header {
  font-size: 38pt;
}

#fix {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width:95%;
  left:2.5%;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="height=1440">
  <title>ВЫЛЕТ</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <div id="fix">

        <table class="lux">

          <thead id="header">
            <tr>
              <th id="head" colspan="5">ООО</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="headTime" colspan="1">8:47</th>
              <th class="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
              <th id="headLable" colspan="1">ВЫЛЕТ</th>
              <th class="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
              <th class="headTime" colspan="1">21.02.2018</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="lable">РЕЙС</th>
              <th class="lable">ПУНКТ НАЗНАЧЕНИЯ</th>
              <th class="lable">КОД</th>
              <th class="lable">РАСПИСАНИЕ</th>
              <th class="lable">ВРЕМЯ ДО ВЫЛЕТА</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <table class="lux">



          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2132</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Стамбул</td>
              <td class="body">IST</td>
              <td class="body">12:50</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:02</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2142</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Анталья</td>
              <td class="body">AYT</td>
              <td class="body">12:55</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:07</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1402</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Екатеринбург</td>
              <td class="body">SVX</td>
              <td class="body">13:00</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:12</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4175</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Белгород</td>
              <td class="body">EGO</td>
              <td class="body">13:00</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:12</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4167</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
              <td class="body">LED</td>
              <td class="body">13:00</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:12</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2462</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Париж</td>
              <td class="body">PAR</td>
              <td class="body">13:05</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:17</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU018</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
              <td class="body">LED</td>
              <td class="body">13:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2022</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Прага</td>
              <td class="body">PRG</td>
              <td class="body">13:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1008</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
              <td class="body">KGD</td>
              <td class="body">13:20</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:32</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4277</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Ереван</td>
              <td class="body">EVN</td>
              <td class="body">13:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1226</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Нижний Новгород</td>
              <td class="body">GOJ</td>
              <td class="body">13:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2514</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Барселона</td>
              <td class="body">BCN</td>
              <td class="body">13:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1124</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
              <td class="body">AER</td>
              <td class="body">13:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1312</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
              <td class="body">MRV</td>
              <td class="body">13:40</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:52</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1492</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Салехард</td>
              <td class="body">SLY</td>
              <td class="body">13:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2096</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Белград</td>
              <td class="body">BEG</td>
              <td class="body">13:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2588</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Лондон</td>
              <td class="body">LON</td>
              <td class="body">13:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">4:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2100</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Рига</td>
              <td class="body">RIX</td>
              <td class="body">13:50</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:02</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1848</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Кишинев</td>
              <td class="body">KIV</td>
              <td class="body">13:55</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:07</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU038</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
              <td class="body">LED</td>
              <td class="body">14:00</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:12</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1648</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Нижневартовск</td>
              <td class="body">NJC</td>
              <td class="body">14:05</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:17</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4523</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Симферополь</td>
              <td class="body">SIP</td>
              <td class="body">14:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1156</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Ростов -на-Дону</td>
              <td class="body">ROV</td>
              <td class="body">14:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2356</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Вена</td>
              <td class="body">VIE</td>
              <td class="body">14:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1506</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Тюмень</td>
              <td class="body">TJM</td>
              <td class="body">14:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1624</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Симферополь</td>
              <td class="body">SIP</td>
              <td class="body">14:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU508</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Тель-Авив</td>
              <td class="body">TLV</td>
              <td class="body">14:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1422</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Челябинск</td>
              <td class="body">CEK</td>
              <td class="body">14:20</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:32</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1232</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Уфа</td>
              <td class="body">UFA</td>
              <td class="body">14:25</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:37</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1212</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Самара</td>
              <td class="body">KUF</td>
              <td class="body">14:25</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:37</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2074</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Ларнака</td>
              <td class="body">LCA</td>
              <td class="body">14:25</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:37</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1104</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Краснодар</td>
              <td class="body">KRR</td>
              <td class="body">14:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1202</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Пермь</td>
              <td class="body">PEE</td>
              <td class="body">14:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1768</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Пермь</td>
              <td class="body">PEE</td>
              <td class="body">14:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1182</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Волгоград</td>
              <td class="body">VOG</td>
              <td class="body">14:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU102</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Нью-Йорк</td>
              <td class="body">NYC</td>
              <td class="body">14:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2408</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Рим</td>
              <td class="body">ROM</td>
              <td class="body">14:40</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:52</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2694</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Амстердам</td>
              <td class="body">AMS</td>
              <td class="body">14:40</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:52</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1142</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Анапа</td>
              <td class="body">AAQ</td>
              <td class="body">14:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2154</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Дюссельдорф</td>
              <td class="body">DUS</td>
              <td class="body">14:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1330</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Архангельск</td>
              <td class="body">ARH</td>
              <td class="body">14:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">5:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2412</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Милан</td>
              <td class="body">MIL</td>
              <td class="body">14:50</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:02</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2458</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Париж</td>
              <td class="body">PAR</td>
              <td class="body">14:50</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:02</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1010</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
              <td class="body">KGD</td>
              <td class="body">14:55</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:07</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2014</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Прага</td>
              <td class="body">PRG</td>
              <td class="body">14:55</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:07</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2328</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Мюнхен</td>
              <td class="body">MUC</td>
              <td class="body">14:55</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:07</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU020</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
              <td class="body">LED</td>
              <td class="body">15:00</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:12</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1252</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Нижнекамск</td>
              <td class="body">NBC</td>
              <td class="body">15:05</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:17</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2302</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Франкфурт-на-Майне</td>
              <td class="body">FRA</td>
              <td class="body">15:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU234</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Дели</td>
              <td class="body">DEL</td>
              <td class="body">15:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2656</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Франкфурт-на-Майне</td>
              <td class="body">FRA</td>
              <td class="body">15:10</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:22</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1842</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Минск</td>
              <td class="body">MSQ</td>
              <td class="body">15:15</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:27</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1108</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Краснодар</td>
              <td class="body">KRR</td>
              <td class="body">15:25</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:37</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2314</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Берлин</td>
              <td class="body">BER</td>
              <td class="body">15:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4183</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
              <td class="body">MRV</td>
              <td class="body">15:30</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:42</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1174</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Астрахань</td>
              <td class="body">ASF</td>
              <td class="body">15:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4133</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Симферополь</td>
              <td class="body">SIP</td>
              <td class="body">15:35</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:47</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1126</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
              <td class="body">AER</td>
              <td class="body">15:40</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:52</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1324</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Мурманск</td>
              <td class="body">MMK</td>
              <td class="body">15:40</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:52</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1192</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Казань</td>
              <td class="body">KZN</td>
              <td class="body">15:45</td>

              <td class="bodyTime">6:57</td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4225</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
              <td class="body">AER</td>
              <td class="body">15:50</td>


              <td class="body">7:02</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">AF1045</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Париж</td>
              <td class="body">PAR</td>
              <td class="body">15:55</td>


              <td class="body">7:07</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1248</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Оренбург</td>
              <td class="body">REN</td>
              <td class="body">15:55</td>


              <td class="body">7:07</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1404</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Екатеринбург</td>
              <td class="body">SVX</td>
              <td class="body">16:05</td>


              <td class="body">7:17</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU522</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Дубай</td>
              <td class="body">DXB</td>
              <td class="body">16:05</td>


              <td class="body">7:17</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU022</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Санкт-Петербург</td>
              <td class="body">LED</td>
              <td class="body">16:10</td>


              <td class="body">7:22</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1700</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Владивосток</td>
              <td class="body">VVO</td>
              <td class="body">16:10</td>


              <td class="body">7:22</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4305</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Хабаровск</td>
              <td class="body">KHV</td>
              <td class="body">16:15</td>


              <td class="body">7:27</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU2352</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Вена</td>
              <td class="body">VIE</td>
              <td class="body">16:20</td>


              <td class="body">7:32</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4227</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Волгоград</td>
              <td class="body">VOG</td>
              <td class="body">16:20</td>


              <td class="body">7:32</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">BT429</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Рига</td>
              <td class="body">RIX</td>
              <td class="body">16:25</td>


              <td class="body">7:37</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1004</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
              <td class="body">KGD</td>
              <td class="body">16:30</td>


              <td class="body">7:42</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1742</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Южно-Сахалинск</td>
              <td class="body">UUS</td>
              <td class="body">16:35</td>


              <td class="body">7:47</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1862</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Ереван</td>
              <td class="body">EVN</td>
              <td class="body">16:40</td>


              <td class="body">7:52</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">SU1630</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Симферополь</td>
              <td class="body">SIP</td>
              <td class="body">16:40</td>


              <td class="body">7:52</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="bodyleft">N4165</td>
              <td class="bodyleft">Казань</td>
              <td class="body">KZN</td>
              <td class="body">16:45</td>


              <td class="body">7:57</td>

            </tr>

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>

    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```